# there is a fatal error what it means and how to solve i try to get text from textfield in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3

```
class Logincontroller: UIViewController
{
    @IBOutlet weak var login_tf_uname: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var login_tf_pwd: UITextField!

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }


    @IBAction func submit(_ sender: Any)
    {
        let uid = login_tf_uname.text!
        print(uid)
        let pwd = login_tf_pwd.text!
        print(pwd)
    }

}
```

Comment: please help me to solve this error

Comment: use if let uid = login_tf_uname.text! else use if  !login_tf_uname.text!.isEmpty

Comment: its not working

Comment: I think textfield outlet is not properly connected
That why it returns nil